# how to add worksheet in the excel workbook using php

Tags: php, excel

how to i add the worksheet in the excel work book using php.

i am using this code to to write text in the excel sheet using php

```
            include("excelwriter.inc.php");

    $excel=new ExcelWriter("myXls.xls");

    if($excel==false)
        echo $excel->error;


    $excel->writeLine($myArr);
    $myArr=array("Recurring Payment / Deduct (Info Type P0014)");
    $excel->writeLine($myArr);
    $myArr=array(" ");
    $excel->writeLine($myArr);
            $excel->close();
    $filesh = "myXls.xls";

    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($filesh));
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    readfile($filesh);
```

**excelwriter.inc.php**

```
      */
    function writeRow()
    {
        if($this->state!="OPENED")
        {
            $this->error="Error : Please open the file.";
            return false;
        }   
        if($this->newRow==false)
            fwrite($this->fp,"<tr>");
        else
            fwrite($this->fp,"</tr><tr>");
        $this->newRow=true; 
    }

    /*
    * @Params : $value : Coloumn Value
    * @Return : Void
    */
    function writeCol($value)
    {
        if($this->state!="OPENED")
        {
            $this->error="Error : Please open the file.";
            return false;
        }   
        fwrite($this->fp,"<td class=xl24 width=64 >$value</td>");
    }
}
```

But i did't know how to add the worksheet in the excel book please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though the ExcelWriter library that you're using is actually writing an HTML table rather than a real Excel file. To create a workbook with more than one worksheet, you'll need to use a library that generates **real** Excel files, such as [PHPExcel](http://www.phpexcel.net) rather than trying to con MS Excel into believing that HTML markup is a real spreadsheet